# Twitter button count not work, it always displays 0

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, twitter

Script :

```
<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

code :

```
<?php
      $variable = '<a name="twitter_share" href="http://twitter.com/share" data-url="'.urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)).'" data-counturl="'.urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)).'" data-count="horizontal" class="twitter-share-button" >Tweet</a>';
?>
```

It tweets successfully but in my site page icon not count the number of tweet, it remains same value 0.

solution accepted,
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can we see the full code. The second line of code you've given us looks like it should be within php tags and is part of an echo/return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out this questions answer from here,

[twitter button](https://about.twitter.com/resources/buttons)